# Outputting a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, output, display

I have 3 methods to 1. Take in strings as an array [zipCodes], 2. Output a menu for the user and 3. display the string array back to the user. The first 2 options are working and after testing I can say that the array is working and taking in strings, however I am having bother displaying them back to the user.

I have used this method with ints, it makes me think that the [i] is only for 1 character, an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

// Here is the code so far

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] zipCodes = new string[10];
            string zCounter;

            for (int i = 0; i < zipCodes.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter 10 destinations:");
                zCounter = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                zCounter = zipCodes[i];
            }

            int sentinalNo;

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter from the following options: ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Display order zipcodes.");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Search zipcode.");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Exit.");
            sentinalNo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (sentinalNo != 3)
            {
                switch (sentinalNo)
                {
                    case 1:
                        DisplayZips(zipCodes);
                        break;
                }

            }


        }

        private static void DisplayZips(string[] zipCodes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < zipCodes.Length; i++)
            {
                // Why doesnt this work?
                Console.WriteLine(zipCodes[i]);
            }
```

Comment: `F9` , `F5` , `F10` ,`F11`,  are those magic strings?

Comment: @Quantic As you might know, they are the most used keys when using VS debugger :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign input into the array items:

```
        // array of 10 strings each of them is null
        string[] zipCodes = new string[10];
        ... 

        for (int i = 0; i < zipCodes.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 10 destinations:");
            // Convert.ToString is redundant here
            zCounter = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            // swapped: user input is assigned to array items
            zipCodes[i] = zCounter;
        }
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, So what type of date is the array storing that I didnt declare that?

Comment: `string[] zipCodes = new string[10];` creates an array instance with 10 `null` items

Comment: I know this sounds like a stupid question, but is there any reason to not declare the data type in an array or is it just common knowledge to always do this?

Comment: Note that this will print each item in the array now, but infinitely because of the while loop the method is being called in so the OP will need to address that as well.

Comment: Well, you can put `var zipCodes = new string[10];` instead of `string[] = new string[10];` (If I understand right "not declare the data type in an array"), often `var` is more readable.

Comment: With regards to the continuous loop -  I have used this method on previous projects with it working, What is wrong in this case? (I know its not working)

Comment: The loop itself `for (int i = 0; i < zipCodes.Length; i++)` is OK; the assignment `zCounter = zipCodes[i];` is wrong it should be swapped `zipCodes[i] = zCounter;`